# Finding $\mathbb{E}(\xi|\eta)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-expectation, density-function

Vector $(\xi, \eta)$ is evenly distributed in set $D=\{  (x,y): 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y \leq 1, x+y \leq 1   \}$. I need to find $\mathbb{E}(\xi|\eta)$.

So first of all I found the size of $D$. It is $\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)dx= \frac{1}{2}.$

Now I think I need to find the density function $p(x,y)$. How could I find it? Is it 2?

Than am I right $p_1(x) = 2(1-x)$ and  $p_2(y)=2y?$

Next step maybe should be finding $p_2(y|x)$ and $p_1(x|y)$ and after than I can find $\mathbb{E}(\xi|\eta)$. Am I right? How to find all those density functions?

Comment: Yes. The distribution possesses the value of $2$ throughout $D$

Comment: @MostafaAyaz yes! Is it because $1/|\mathcal{D}|$?

Comment: Without mentioning support, density function is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

The area enclosed by the region $D$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Hence the density of $(X,Y)$ uniform on $D$ is

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=2\,\mathbf1_{0<x,y<1\,,\,x+y<1}$$

Rewriting the above we see that the density factors as

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\underbrace{\frac{1}{1-y}\mathbf1_{0<x<1-y}}_{f_{X\mid Y}(x)}\,\,\underbrace{2(1-y)\mathbf1_{0<y<1}}_{f_Y(y)}$$

So $X\mid Y$ is uniformly distributed over $(0,1-Y)$, giving $$E(X\mid Y)=\frac{1-Y}{2}$$

Comment: I don't understand how did you get the second line... I trying to find $p_1(x)$ and $p_2 (y)$.

Comment: @Atstovas $f_{X,Y}$ is the joint density of $(X,Y)$, what you are calling $p(x,y)$. $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. Your $p_1,p_2$ is my $f_X,f_Y$, where $f_X(x)=\int_0^{1-x} 2\,dy\,\mathbf1_{0<x<1}$. The conditional density of $Y\mid X$ is $f_{Y\mid X}(y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$ and similarly for $X\mid Y$.

Comment: Okey, so how should I do if I want also to find $\mathbb{E}(\eta|\xi)?$

Comment: @Atstovas That should be obvious. You tell me. I gave you pretty much everything to answer the question.

Comment: is $f_Y(x)=\int_{1-y}^1 2dx \mathbf{1}_{0<y<1}?$

Comment: @Atstovas As I said before, $f_X=f_Y$. Considering the symmetry of $X$ and $Y$, isn't it sufficient to find distribution of $Y$, distribution of $X\mid Y$, $\quad E(X\mid Y)$ to answer the same for $X$, $\quad Y\mid X$, $\quad E(Y\mid X)$ and vice-versa?